# JQuery - moving images based on time conditional

Tags: jquery, image, time, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble writing a JQuery function that will move an image of a sun diagonally from bottom-left to top-right before 6pm and, once the time variable hits 6pm, makes a moon image rise diagonally to top-right while the sun sets back to it's original position. Thanks for any help.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">    

var objDate = new Date();
var time = objDate.getHours();

        $(document).ready(function() {
           if (time < 18)
                $("sun").animate({
                  'left' : "+=30px", 
                  'top' : "-=30px" 
                }, 5000);
                $('moon').animate({
                  'left' : "-=30px", 
                  'top' : "+=30px" 
                }, 5000);

           if (time > 18)
                $("sun").animate({
                  'left' : "-=30px", 
                  'top' : "+=30px" 
                }, 5000);
                $("moon").animate({
                  'left' : "+=30px", 
                  'top' : "-=30px" 
                }, 5000);
            });

</script>



<style type="text/css">
        #citiscape{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 5;
            background-image: url(city.png);
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #sun {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 250px;
            top: 400px;
            z-index: 2;
            background-image: url(sun.jpg)
        }

        #moon {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 500px;
            top: 650px;
            z-index: 3;
            background-image: url(moon.png); 
            background-size: cover;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }                   
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="citiscape"></div>
<div id="sun"></div> 
<div id="moon"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having?

Comment: I wish I knew exactly. The images won't move though. Is there anything that pops out at you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not beign able to animate because your jQuery selectors are wrong. It's waiting for a CSS selector.

```
 $("sun").animate //"sun" is not a CSS selector

 $("#sun").animate //"#sun" (ID) is the correct one.
```

Comment: Same issue with the "moon"